# Online etymology dictionaries for French, beyond CNTRL?

Tags: etymology, resource-request, french, dictionary

Are there etymology dictionaries for French available on the Internet?  To wit, what's a French equivalent of http://etymonline.com/?

I already know about
[TLF  informatisé (TLFi)](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/), but often, it does not retrograde to Latin and PIE etymons;
[Littré](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionnaire_de_la_langue_fran%C3%A7aise_(Littr%C3%A9)) suffers from the same problem as TLFi, but is abrupter.

PS: [This Area 51 question](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82841/language-learning/82844#82844) is similar.

Answer (score 5):

If you have access to a good library you can consult von Wartburg's  Französisches Etymologisches Wörterbuch in 25 volumes. There is also an abridged French translation.

Comment: [Link](http://stella.atilf.fr/scripts/mep.exe?CRITERE=BIENVENUE;ISIS=mep_few.txt;OUVRIR_MENU=1;s=s0f4d20d0;ISIS=mep_few.txt;s=s0f4d20d0;;ISIS=mep_few.txt)

Answer (score 4):

The  [Littré](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionnaire_de_la_langue_fran%C3%A7aise_(Littr%C3%A9)) is available online free of charge. It is old (1877) but can provide some interesting etymological insights

[Example](http://www.littre.org/definition/bichet):

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but Littré lacks sufficient details for many entries. I did know about it before, but I should've professed this. So would you mind please converting your answer into a comment?

Comment: @LePressentiment Sorry comments get deleted too easily on SE.

Answer (score 4):

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org) has etymology entries going back to Old French, Latin, and Proto-Indo-European (PIE), e.g., https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bleu#Etymology.

Answer (score 1):

The text of "An etymological dictionary of the French language" is available at https://archive.org/stream/etymologicaldict00bracrich/etymologicaldict00bracrich_djvu.txt

Answer (score 1):

Limited etymological info for French (40,000 words), along with around 20 other languages: https://etymologeek.com/fra/a